# How do I sort an array of (Int, String) by Int value?

Tags: arrays, swift

```
var array = [(Int, String)]()
```

I need the pairs in the array sorted in ascending order by the value of the Int.

```
array = [(2, "is"), (0, "Hello"), (1, "this"), (3, "Ben")]
```

I need this to return:

```
array = [(0, "Hello"), (1, "this"), (2, "is"), (3, "Ben")]
```

I think some variation of the following should work, but I can't figure out how to set it up.

```
array.sortInPlace()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
let array = [(2, "is"), (0, "Hello"), (1, "this"), (3, "Ben")]
let sortedArray = array.sort { $0.0 < $1.0 }

print(sortedArray) // [(0, "Hello"), (1, "this"), (2, "is"), (3, "Ben")]
```

The `.0` part represents the first object of the tuple.

*See Matt's answer for the mutable version.*

Comment: I'm not even joking when I say this answer (and question) changed my life. Tuples.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
var array = [(2, "is"), (0, "Hello"), (1, "this"), (3, "Ben")]
array.sortInPlace{$0.0 < $1.0}
```